# How to write LINQ which function same as SQL like?

Tags: linq

How to write linq with same function of following sql Like:

```
select * from table where col like param?
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Table.Where(t => t.col.Contains(param));
```

...should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator.aspx

Digging into System.Data.Linq.SqlClient namespace, I found a little helper class called SqlMethods, which can be very usefull in such scenarios. SqlMethods has a method called Like, that can be used in a Linq to SQL query:

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where SqlMethods.Like(c.City, "L_n%")
            select c;
```

This method gets the string expression to check (the customer's city in this example) and the patterns to test against which is provided in the same way you'd write a LIKE clause in SQL.

Using the above query generated the required SQL statement:

```
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ...
FROM   dbo.Customers
WHERE  City LIKE [L_n%]
```

Comment: Is it just me, or is this overkill when Contains does what he needs?

Comment: @Justin Niessner: no argument here. I did a Google search before any other answers were listed and this is what I found.

Comment: @Dinah Fair enough. Contains() will usually work for most cases. SqlMethods.Like() is for the more complex cases where the developer wants more control over the generated SQL.

Comment: Very interesting! System.Data.Linq.SqlClient is not available for silverlight at client site.

Answer (score 2):

```
var selection = records.Where (r => r.Col.Contains (param));
```

Comment: StartsWith also translates to LIKE in SQL according to http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/archive/2007/08/12/linq-2-sql-string-functions.aspx

Comment: Interesting, however not obvious. Belongs to tricks you need to know. For better maintainability I would stick with "Contains" or "Like" as Dinah suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = from SomeCollection where someCondition select I;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains clause in Linq which is same as Sql Like. You can find code as following.

`var query = from e in emp
        where e.name.Contains("Mark")
        select e;`